# 1C Битрикс - выполняется редирект, хотя в .htaccess его нет (возможно хостинг?)

Tags: php, .htaccess, битрикс

Сайт доступен по 3 адресам:

- example.com
- example.ru
- сайт.рф

Основной - example.ru.

При попытке запроса www.сайт.рф идет перенаправление на [https://www.сайт.рф](https://www.%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84). Сертификата у домена нет, сайт не открывается. С остальными доменами проблема не наблюдается.

В .htaccess ничего подобного не прописано, как и на стороне хостинга.

Что может такого быть в Битриксе, что устраивает такую подлянку?

Добавил в .htaccess следующее для склейки сайта в варианте без www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

для англоязычных доменов сработало, но сайт.рф все так же перенаправляется на https-версию. Получается, дело все-таки в хостинге?

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю что:

1. Там вообще может быть nginx и на htaccess ему пофиг
2. В настройках bitrix есть в пару мест где можно указать https смотри низ мануала https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=35&LESSON_ID=3261